# Flask: Find first open port

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, http, flask

How can I find the first open HTTP port on my computer, and start a Flask server running on it?

I will run the app like this:

```
app.run(port=first_open_port, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It probably feels like a hack, but at least in development (which is the only time they recommend you use `app.run` anyway) you can simply start with a port number, wrap the app.run in a try:except: block, and if it throws a socket.error you increment your candidate port# and retry.

```
for port in range(100, 5000):
    try:
        app.run(port=port)
        break
    except socket.error:
        pass
```